# Security for adding case teams to cases

Tags: case, flow, process-builder, assignment-rules, case-teams

I have a flow that creates a case with the info entered by the user. 
I want to add a default case team to it; however, it gives an error saying the user does not have create rights for the "CaseTeamTemplateRecord" object. In other words, the user does not have the rights to add case teams to the case. 
I cannot use assignment rules because flows do not trigger assignment rules. Process builder does not let me create CaseTeamTemplateRecord objects. I would only like to use an apex trigger as a last resort.

I think my solution would be to give rights to users to add case teams to cases... How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you found a solution to your question , but here is the answer if you want to use trigger- http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/running-case-assignment-rules-from-apex